# Magento : Product Images and browse and Upload button Missing

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, file-upload

I have no solutions found since last one week. In My magento 1.9.3.1 all product images and browse file button and upload files button are missing on product edit in admin show in screen-sort. kindly help me to revert back.

[image]

Comment: did you checked in other browsers regarding browse buttons, you may need adobe flash player , also is images not displaying in `site & in backend` ?

Comment: did you got solution ?

Answer (score 2):

These buttons are coming from flash.So check your media folder on following location

design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media

if there is no media folder then copy from fresh magento

This will solve your problem :) if not Try solution from below links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022532/image-upload-buttons-are-missing-in-magento-in-back-end

Answer (score 2):

I solved in this way:

- Use the Firefox browser
- Update Adobe Flash Player version
- Restart Firefox browser
- Go to product images in admin
- Allow the flash player on browser (alert on the top left)

For use in Google Chrome enable website in setting -  https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enabling-flash-player-chrome.html

For Safari - https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enabling-flash-player-safari.html

Comment: Disable sites to ask first in Chrome