# Cannot upload product images to my web page

Tags: magento-1.8, ce-1.8.1.0, image-upload

---

I cannot upload **product images** to my **website** and it is doing my head in!!!  I usually can, but it's not showing me the **"BROWSE FILE" "UPLOAD FILE"**.  I am going bananas over this!  I have **refreshed the CACHE** etc and still no luck.  I'm not a computer programmer or anything and when this has happened in the past, I usually have to ensure **ADOBE** is running (which it is) and **refresh the Cache**.

Could someone assist or give me advice as I need to upload product images ASAP.  I'm using **Magento 1.8.0.0**

Thank you
Tan
(Female in Distress)

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [magento-product-images-and-browse-and-upload-button-missing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155257/magento-product-images-and-browse-and-upload-button-missing)

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Install/Update flash player and try again

please refer to the link that ChrisC has given:

[Magento : Product Images and browse and Upload button Missing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155257/magento-product-images-and-browse-and-upload-button-missing)