# Magento 1.9.2.4 : Product Images and browse and Upload button Missing

Tags: magento-1.9, product, image

I am using Magento ver. 1.9.2.4, I have tried all solution available on different threads but unable to get "Browse Button" and "Upload Button" in product image tab. I have tried chrome, MicrosoftEdge, Opera and Firefox but not successful. Please suggest me a solution as soon as possible. 
Thanks

Comment: Very common issue.
 It mean you need to update security patches in your site.

Comment: can you please guide me a bit more what exactly i need to do. Thanks

Comment: Gohil Rajesh : It didn't work. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

please try once this module. it will help you

> https://github.com/openstream/No-Flash-Image-Uploader

Comment: please guide where to upload "Just upload the app and js folders to your Magento installation". there are already folders of app and js in public_html/app and public_html/js. Shall i replace them? or something else. Thanks

Comment: Yes just upload..overwrite folder..dont remove old app and js

Comment: i have not overwritten those folder but uploaded the missing files from here "No-Flash-Image-Uploader: Just upload the app and js folders to your Magento installation". but on images catalog_product/edit only "Images" is written, nothing else. i had a fear if i overwrite the complete folders "app and js" the whole website will be affected. because overwrite the folders mean replacing all their files with new files. Please guide what to do. thanks

Comment: What u mean by this? It works or not?

Comment: no it didnot work

Comment: i didn't overwrite both folder due to fear of destruction of website. i just uploaded the selected files

Comment: I don't get what exactly you did..its a basic flow for install module in magento 1.

Comment: Clear cache after upload all modules folder and file

Comment: Dont worry module will not replace any files..module has own files.

Comment: i did same now what you said but it didn't work. i can't see the product -> edit section. Its a blank page with text "Images" just. cleared cache as well but still not working.

Comment: Any other solution please?

Comment: you uploaded magento security patches in your site?? I mean after that issue occuring?

Comment: yes, before uploading product edit section was being opened, but only browse n upload buttons were not displaying. After upladed security patches, product edit section is displaying a blank page with just text "Images".

Comment: Is there any other solution?

Comment: sorry I can't say u exact solution because there are lot of  reason behind it. please check here might it helps you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155257/magento-product-images-and-browse-and-upload-button-missing

Comment: It was working before December 31, 2020, when browsers blocked flash content since that its not working. As in latest browers the flash content is completly blocked. If you have any solution to run flash content in browsers please share.